# Count $_FILES return 1 when no files are uploaded

Tags: php, file, file-upload, count

I have a very simple field to upload files.

I'm counting the files uploaded with the php function `count($_FILES["name"]["tmp_name"]);`

However, when I don't upload any files, and leave the input blank, the count keep returning `1` as if a file was uploaded.

Does anyone knows how to fix that ?

Comment: Use function [`is_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php) to find out if a file was uploaded.

Comment: If you want to use `count()` specify that you want to check multidimensional arrays. Check the [documentation on 'mode'](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) for more information.

Comment: @tomudding By adding the `COUNT_RECURSIVE` it's doesn't change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) is used to count the elements of an array or the properties of an object that implements the [`Countable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php) interface (it calls the `count()` method of the object.)

Given a value that is not one of the above (array or object that implements `Countable`), `count()` returns `1` with only one exception: `count(NULL)` is `0`.

`$_FILES["name"]["tmp_name"]` is a string, no matter if a file was uploaded or not. `count($_FILES["name"]["tmp_name"])` is always `1`.

Use the function [`is_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php) to find out if a file was uploaded.